# Loop function to grab mean value into new data frame return subset error

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have large amount of file,but lets start with file 1:N. There are data frame inside each file. each file contain the same header but different in rows number including some error and missing number here and there. I want to get mean value from specific column (temp_c) from each file and make a new list/data frame from it. 'dat' below is one example from one of the file content. Please give me a hand..

```
head(dat)
  X pres_hpa hght_m temp_c dwpt_c relh_pct mixr_g_kg drct_deg sknt_knot thta_k thte_k thtv_k
1 1   1008.0     16   24.0   19.1       74     14.00      230         7  296.5  337.1  299.0
2 2   1007.8     18   24.0   19.1       74     14.00      230         7  296.5  337.1  299.0
3 3   1000.0     88   23.8   18.8       74     13.85      229         8  296.9  337.2  299.4
4 4    975.7    304   24.4   17.8       67     13.34      225        10  299.7  338.9  302.1
5 5    970.0    355   24.6   17.6       65     13.23      224        11  300.4  339.4  302.7
6 6    909.5    914   21.7   14.7       64     11.67      210        19  302.9  337.8  305.1
        date from_hr to_hr
1 1981-11-01       0     0
2 1981-11-01       0     0
3 1981-11-01       0     0
4 1981-11-01       0     0
5 1981-11-01       0     0
6 1981-11-01       0     0  

y = 1978
N <- 3
for (i in 1:N) {
  yr = y +(as.numeric(i))
  yr = as.character(yr)
  p <- paste0("c:/Users/climatology/yr/",yr,".csv")
  print(p)
  #read.csv
  dat <- read.csv(p,header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)
  #filter
  dat_sub <- filter(dat, pres_hpa == 1000)
  dat_sub <- filter(dat_sub, hght_m > 0)
  dat_sub <- filter(dat_sub, temp_c > 0)
  #grab Mean Value into data frame
  #m = sapply(dat_sub$temp_c,function(i)mean(dat_sub$temp_c))
  data[i] = data.frame(index = i, year = as.numeric(yr), temp = 
  mean(dat_sub$temp_c))
}

Error in data[i] <- data.frame(index = i, year = as.numeric(yr), temp = mean(dat_sub$temp_c)) : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Comment: You need to define `data<-list()` ahead of for loop. Then `data[[i]]<-data.frame()`. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

data is not subsettable because it is a function. You try to select the first item of data but data is not define in your code (and is a function btw)